# Existing RSS feeds do not pick up tag changes

Tags: support, bug, feed

Before requesting that the [ibm-bluemix](/questions/tagged/ibm-bluemix) tag be renamed to [ibm-cloud](/questions/tagged/ibm-cloud), I posted a series of questions about the renaming process here: [Questions regarding the tag merging/synonym impact](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303772/questions-regarding-the-tag-merging-synonym-impact)

Now that the tag has been changed, I have noticed that RSS feeds are not accurate. If you have an existing feed that is looking for the [ibm-bluemix](/questions/tagged/ibm-bluemix) tagged content, it DOES NOT include any new content that was not originally tagged as [ibm-bluemix](/questions/tagged/ibm-bluemix).

For example:

- From before the rename, if you created content that was tagged [ibm-bluemix](/questions/tagged/ibm-bluemix) and renamed [ibm-cloud](/questions/tagged/ibm-cloud) by the back-end process, that content **IS** included in the RSS feed looking for content tagged with [ibm-bluemix](/questions/tagged/ibm-bluemix).
- If you create new content using the [ibm-cloud](/questions/tagged/ibm-cloud) tag, it **IS NOT** included in any original RSS feeds looking for the [ibm-bluemix](/questions/tagged/ibm-bluemix) tag.

The RSS feed apparently does not adjust and look for the parent tag when [ibm-bluemix](/questions/tagged/ibm-bluemix) is a synonym.

This issue is a HUGE problem as all original RSS feeds looking for [ibm-bluemix](/questions/tagged/ibm-bluemix) tagged content will need to be updated to look for [ibm-cloud](/questions/tagged/ibm-cloud). We have teams that follow the RSS feeds to see when people ask questions about their area of focus.

You can see the difference here:

- [ibm-cloud] tagged content RSS feed: https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=ibm-cloud&sort=newest
- [ibm-bluemix] tagged content RSS feed: https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=ibm-bluemix&sort=newest
  New attempts to follow this RSS feed result in a "not found" error message when trying to add it as a Live Feed Bookmark to FireFox. An existing RSS feed is missing the latest [ibm-cloud](/questions/tagged/ibm-cloud)entries from the last few days after the rename/synonym change.

This issue seems to be a bug in how the RSS feeds work. Can someone investigate and hopefully fix it?