# How are tag-watch and tag RSS feeds affected by synonyms and renaming?

Tags: support, tag-synonyms, feed, tag-watching

I am interested in how **tag-watching** and **tag RSS feeds** are affected by:

1. Adding a tag as a synonym
2. Renaming a tag (via merge)

Consider the following scenarios:

**Scenario 1:** (synonyms)

- A user is watching tag [topic](/questions/tagged/topic) and has an RSS feed subscription to it. Now, a synonym [similar-topic](/questions/tagged/similar-topic) for [topic](/questions/tagged/topic) has been approved.

  - does the user automatically start watching [similar-topic](/questions/tagged/similar-topic)?
  - does the user receive new questions in his/her RSS feed for the [similar-topic](/questions/tagged/similar-topic)?

**Scenario 2:** (Renaming)

- A user is watching tag [topic-with-typo](/questions/tagged/topic-with-typo) and has the RSS feed subscription to it. Now, this tag is renamed by a moderator via merge to [topic-without-typo](/questions/tagged/topic-without-typo)

  - does the user automatically start watching [topic-without-typo](/questions/tagged/topic-without-typo)?
  - does the user receive new questions in his/her RSS feed for the [topic-without-typo](/questions/tagged/topic-without-typo)?

Other relevant and irrelevant information:

- was not able to find anything via [this search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Btag-synonyms%5D%20watch) and [this search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Btag-watch%5D%20synonym)
- [Feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304290/383809) on RSS feeds with similar claims. Low votes, no answers, not clear enough.

Answer (score 2):

### **Scenario 2: renaming via merge**

Watched (favourited) and ignored tags are definitely remapped, and I'd guess the RSS thing is too.

You can actually see this noted on the report page you get after merging two tags. Here's a screenshot I saved from a couple of years ago:

[image]